# Haskell Language Server - linker error: symbol sqlite3_fts3_may_be_corrupt

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program, nix, nix-shell, haskell-language-server

When I run haskell-language-server in nix-shell in plutus-pioneer-progam i get this error.

````
   sqlite3_fts3_may_be_corrupt
whilst processing object file
   /nix/store/jmhwwzn1yfjzlxavz16afkf1r4shmp8z-persistent-sqlite-lib-persistent-sqlite-2.13.0.3/lib/x86_64-linux-ghc-8.10.4.20210212/persistent-sqlite-2.13.0.3-8rnIaulr0SMFWDeiU7TZN4/HSpersistent-sqlite-2.13.0.3-8rnIaulr0SMFWDeiU7TZN4.o
The symbol was previously defined in
   /nix/store/si95pc9hb5hr1yiyj7b2s75hl4bkn9g2-direct-sqlite-lib-direct-sqlite-2.3.26/lib/x86_64-linux-ghc-8.10.4.20210212/direct-sqlite-2.3.26-Gg0YVBPVrMk3LDxZxB2Bzf/HSdirect-sqlite-2.3.26-Gg0YVBPVrMk3LDxZxB2Bzf.o
This could be caused by:
   * Loading two different object files which export the same symbol
   * Specifying the same object file twice on the GHCi command line
   * An incorrect `package.conf' entry, causing some object to be
     loaded twice.```
````

Comment: Are you on macos?

Answer (score 1):

I've found out that the issue comes from the playground stuff. (don't ask me why...)

Commenting the lines [360 .. 365], 24 and 28, the problem goes away.
Note that doing this, the old friend `GHC Core to PLC plugin; E043:Error` comes up, but at least you can navigate the code and look at the documentation.

Comment: What is the file that needs to be edited ?

Comment: https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-pioneer-program/blob/main/code/week01/src/Week01/EnglishAuction.hs