# Plutus and Haskell live references

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program

I am following the plutus pioneer program as an Haskell newbie.

I am using VSCode to look at the snippets and type my code.

I am wondering what is the best way to integrate (if possible) the languages documentation into the IDE. I would love to just reach the function documentation with a couple of clicks!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use this plugin: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=haskell.haskell

Then from the `nix-shell` run `code .` to start VSCode and to let it use the right haskell-language-server version.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this doesn't work in the plutus pioneer program weeks so far (currently week03). Your IDE uses the haskell language server to get type references but if you run the command `haskell-language-server` in a `nix-shell` in the current week's repository you will get an error. This is documented in this question: [HLS Compiler Error PPP Week01 (WSL2 + VSCode)](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/q/6614/5692)

Answer (score 0):

Try working from https://demeter.run, it should have this (I think)